# Is this good way to query realm in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I want reduce lines of code, (There are many overlapping codes)

So I try move some functions to object class

But is it good way?

```
object RealmManager {
    fun getMemo() : RealmResults<Memo> {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
            return realm.where(Memo::class.java).findAll()
        }
    }

// more codes ~
}
```

Comment: There is a even better way when dealing with kotlin use realm extension functions https://github.com/vicpinm/Kotlin-Realm-Extensions

Comment: Also don't use object class instead move your code into extension file

Comment: thanks @Mr.Patel, I'll try that library.